# Match trigger between two objects

Tags: trigger, salesforce-id

I  want to make a Trigger  to match the Product  , like there are three  objects demand , supply and matches. Both demand ans supply is a look up in Match object. Some fields are there in demand  like product  ,product  type  and same in the supply ..  Demand consits of   buy and supply consists of Sell. I just want to make a trigger  to match the **Sell----> buy and Buy---->Sell**  there is a status field  also in both demand and supply object  and  whenever a status  is "Available" the product  will match in match object .

Any help would be appreciated . 
Thanx

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement in more detail.

Comment: @Anup i am making an  website like OLX or Quiker  and when ever user sell the product   and second user want to buy the product then matches should generate in the match object . Thats it

Comment: When will your trigger fire? Whats the business requirement behind writing a trigger?

Comment: @TestUser it will fire when the   status="Available"   and  product and  product type will same. Like seller want to sell and buyer want to buy.. if the  condition is met then trigger will fire .

Comment: So you just want to create records of match object when status is available? Whats the exact thing that you want to achieve? Please elaborate.

Comment: @TestUser   Yes.. actually i just want to create a  matches on  behalf of   product , product type and Status. By default status is **pending** and whenever user enter the requirement then  status will automatically be change from pending to **Available** . and when status=Available then matches will generate .  so that user can choose according  to their requirement .. if the requirement met then  after matches it will move to  make a deal.. Are you able to understood my scenario ??

Comment: Instead of writing trigger, you can go for a junction object Match wherein you'll b able to create matches for each Supply and Demand record pair.

Comment: @TestUser  how it is possible ? can you please help me out ? or It is not possible to write a trigger on match object ??

Comment: You can create Match as junction object in which for each record of Supply and detail objects, you'll get a match record which is pair of supply and demand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22543/discussion-between-sfdc-developer-and-test-user).

Comment: I have implemented this type of scenario before. I believe there is no other option then implementing a trigger on demand to find matching supply & create Match records..& other way around trigger on supply to find matching demands & created match records. @sfdcDeveloper

Comment: @snehakem ahha..!! thanx :)